# How do I select columns on the innermost level of a Pandas DataFrame with multiindexed columns without knowing the amount of levels?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a function that needs to select certain columns in the innermost level of a dataframe with multiindexed columns by name, while also reporting all higher column levels. The names of the columns in the innermost level are consistent, but the amount of multiindex levels above them isn't fixed. I might for instance get

```
    foo      bar      baz
    ham spam ham spam ham spam
0   1   2    2   3    4   42
...
```

or

```
    foo      bar      baz
    one      two      three
    ham spam ham spam ham spam
0   1   2    2   3    4   42
...
```

but want everything that's in the `spam` column for both, i.e.

```
    foo  bar  baz
    spam spam spam
0   2    3    42
...
```

or

```
    foo  bar  baz
    one  two  three
    spam spam spam
0   2    3    42
...
```

respectively. If I had a fixed amount of MultiIndex levels, I could access this by

```py
df.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, ["spam"]]]
```

for two levels,

```py
df.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, :, ["spam"]]]
```

for three and so on, but how do I do it when I don't know the amount of levels?

Answer (score 0):

There might be smarter ways, but the one I got to work was this:

```py
top_level_cols = df.columns.nlevels - 1
top_level_slice = [slice(None)] * top_level_cols
df.loc[:, (*top_level_slice, "spam")]
```

Since `df.loc[:, (slice(None), "spam")]` is just the "less nice" way of writing `df.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, "spam"]` and so on, this'll select all of the columns on all of the levels except for the innermost, in which we then select the specific column we want.